# How to call a function before leaving page via HTML <a> target Attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML  tag with a target attribute. The issue is that I want to prevent the user leaving my site this way without saving his changes.

I tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  myfun();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Also changed my code to:

```
window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Inside event')
    })
```

But that didn't do it...

Answer (score 1):

The `return 'string'` method does not work reliably everywhere. Most, if not all Web browsers won't show a custom message. And you also need to call `preventDefault` on the event:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
  myfun();
  event.preventDefault();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

**EDIT** This will not work using `alert`, `confirm` or `prompt` because it will override the browser's default message before displayed. You can do anything else though:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  console.log('Leaving...');
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Changed my code to this but it still doesn't work: ```window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Inside event')
    })```Any ideas?

Comment: @SteffenEbert you can try `async` which runs asap (when this script is ready) you can also try `onunload` but other than that I don't really know

Comment: How about running the function, then running `e.preventDefault`?